# How to detect the browser tab close event in jquery

Tags: jquery, magento2.3.1, popup, browser

How do i detect the browser event when customer closing the browser tab by clicking X in jquey?

I just want to show popup to the customer while they closing the browser tab.

I have used below code. But no luck

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on('beforeunload',function(){
        alert('hai');
    });

});
```

Even alert is also not showing.
Please guide me to solve it.

Comment: Have you checked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing